# Align dataframes column wise in r

Tags: r

I Have 2 Data frames

1. Train - This has 230 Columns
2. Test  - This has 300 Columns

Before i apply the Algorithm, i want to make sure that the columns in the test Data frame are same as those in Train and the rest of the columns from Test are eliminated.

To Summarize, i want to Align the test and Train Data frame Column Wise.There is a function "Align" in Python to do this however i have the requirement to execute this using.

Please advise.

Comment: If you want the solution in R, please remove the `python` tag.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for R

You can use the names of the columns from Train to select the columns from Test. Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate with the built-in mtcars data

```
Test = mtcars
Train = mtcars[, c(1,3,5)]

## Before
names(Train)
[1] "mpg"  "disp" "drat"
names(Test)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

Test = Test[,names(Train)]

## After
names(Test)
[1] "mpg"  "disp" "drat"
```

Comment: Yes, the above solution will work if the number of columns are less.but in my case i have around 200+ columns...

Comment: @AshwinBaldawa  ?? My answer does not depend on the number of columns.